# Lazarus IDE Do Action while pressing a key

Tags: key, software-design, lazarus

I've wanted to know if i can link a special key (for example the "b" key) to a specific action?

For example when i press the button b that the software closes. Is this possible, if yes how do you do so?

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy to do.

- Create a new forms application.
- Place a TButton on the form.
- Set the button's caption to '&b'.
- On the Events tab in the Object Inspector, click in the OnClick event and enter this code

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Close;
end;
```

- Compile and run the program.
- Press the 'b' key and the form will close and the program will stop.

Comment: Thank you. Can you also map a key (in this case the b-key) to an Xbox Controller button?
I think you commented to one of my questions that you should use TBitBtn when wanting to use Xbox Controller buttons. How does it work when you want to assign a button to a existing key?